# Set Value Entity Regardingobjectid Field With Object Type Code Using C#

Tags: c#, entity, dynamics-crm, metadata

I have an entity. This entity's type is activity. I want to  set this entity's regardingobjectid field value and then i want to create record. Each record's regardingobjectid field can show different entity. Namely i set this field "a" entity, and then i can set this field with "b" entity on next record. I only have "a" and "b" entities's logicalname. I take object type code with using logicalname. And i take entity metadata with this object type code. How can i take entity id from entity metadata or object typecode with using C#. If i take entity id (a or b) and then i will set it to regardingobjectid which is in activity type entity.

Comment: How do you know which entity "A" or "B" to set the activity entities `regardingobjectid` to? Do you query for the record? If so how?

Comment: If activity type entity is filled with A entity and then i must create regardingobjectid with A entity id.

Comment: regardingobjectid is lookup field. And i should have entity id. But i only have (A or B) entityname, object type code and entity meta data.

Comment: You would need to know which record you would want to associate the activity entity with to begin with. Only then you could get the id of the record. For e.g. associate with Entity A where name equals "foo bar". Lookups are 1:N relationship, so just like with any relational data, you would need to know the record beforehand.

Comment: can i set regarding object id with regarding object type code. (if i convert type code to guid)

Comment: Type code is an integer not a guid and is constant for all records of a given entity type, Id is the primary key of the record (new_entityid), two different things. You need the Id of the record to be able to set a lookup value.

Comment: Yes, i want to set this field with this type code. Becuse it represent entity directly.

Comment: This field should show entity name. For example A , B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132237/discussion-between-dynamicallycrm-and-dvlpr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wording is pretty confusing. Here is an example which I think covers what you are trying to achieve.

Create a contact, then create a task with the regarding field populated with the contact.

```
Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
contact["lastname"] = "Test Contact";
Guid contactId = service.Create(contact);

Entity task = new Entity("task");
task["subject"] = "Test Task";
task["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("contact", contactId);
service.Create(task);
```

You could also update an existing task like so:

```
Entity task2 = new Entity("task");
task2.Id = new Guid(...);
task2["regardingobjectid"] = new EntityReference("contact", contactId);
service.Create(task);
```

You can get the record id (for use here `new Guid(...)` or here `contactId`) in a variety of ways.

The record id refers to a specific record in CRM, e.g. a row in a table.

If you have created the record using a service call the id is returned to you 
immediately.

```
Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
...
Guid recordId = service.Create(contact);
```

You can query the record id from CRM. Further reading: [IOrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservice.retrievemultiple.aspx).

```
Guid recordId = Service.RetrieveMultiple(new QueryExpression("contact")).Entities.First().Id;
```

If you have an `Entity` object returned from CRM you always get its record id from the `Id` property.

```
Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
Guid recordId = contact.Id;
```

---

*Side Notes*

**Object Type Code (also know as Entity Type Code)**

This isn't usually used for anything, it's a piece of data that has a small number of uses - I rarely find it useful or use it.

The type code can be used to refer to a type of entity, e.g. contact, case, etc. However it's preferred to use the entity schema name, e.g. `contact`, `incident`, etc.

It's also worth remembering that is isn't reliable - especially in the case of custom entities.

[ObjectTypeCode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.metadata.entitymetadata.objecttypecode.aspx)

> Always use the entity schema name (SchemaName) to refer to a custom
>   entity in code and queries. Do not use the object type code (also
>   referred to as entity type) code because its integer value varies for
>   custom entities in different organizations.

**Metadata Services**

You can use the metadata services to receive (and manipulate) information regarding the configuration of the system. E.g. which entities you have and what fields those entities have. It will not give you information about specific records however.

Further reading: [The metadata and data models in Microsoft Dynamics 365](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309434.aspx).

Comment: you created a new entity. But i already have entity. And i have it's records with Dictionary<string, string>. Namely i only have logicalname and it's records. And after i want to set regardingobjectid like as above 'task' entity. In this way task's regardingobjectid should represent your contact entity.

Comment: I get object type code with entity logical name from meta data. Can i update this regarding object id with object type code. Or can i get entity record guid id with this object type code.

Comment: @Dvlpr, well an update isnt very different to a create - example above. You can only set the `regardingobjectid` with an `EntityReference`, that requires the logical name and Id of a record. I'm not sure where the object type code really comes into this - your question isn't clear.

Comment: task2.Id = new Guid(...);  ... ? How can i fiind this id ? from object type code ? from metadata? or entity record fields ?